# 2SLS regression model with 2 instruments

Tags: regression

I am trying to estimate the impact of sanitation (binary endogenous) on child health (with 4 outcome variables, 2 binary and 2 continuous). I'm using 2 instruments which are continuous.

Is 2SLS appropriate for binary variables such as X and Y or is it better to use biprobit ? I want to use 2SLS with all binary outcome variables.

Answer (score 0):

2SLS is appropriate for binary endogenous variables and binary outcome variables. In fact, it is a common method for estimating the effects of binary endogenous variables on binary or continuous outcome variables.

Bivariate Probit (Biprobit) is also a viable alternative for estimating the effect of a binary endogenous variable on binary outcome variables. Biprobit can handle binary endogenous variables and binary outcomes, but it assumes that the errors in both the endogenous and outcome equations are jointly normally distributed. If this assumption is not met, then Biprobit may not be the best option.

In your case, since you have continuous instruments and binary endogenous variables and binary outcome variables, 2SLS can be used to estimate the causal effect of sanitation on child health. You can use the binary outcome variables as dependent variables in the second stage regression.

It is important to ensure that the instruments used in the analysis satisfy the 2SLS assumptions, particularly the exogeneity and relevance conditions. Additionally, you should also consider other potential confounding variables that could influence the relationship between sanitation and child health, and include them in the analysis as control variables.